# Generate a number of random width and height blocks and fit them full width of the HTML5 canvas - EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I am trying to do the following:

1. Generate a number (specified by var number) of random width and height blocks
2. Fill these blocks to 100% width of the canvas

My code so far

```
function init() {
    //find canvas and load images, wait for last image to load
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    // set width and height
    stage.canvas.width = 500;
    stage.canvas.height = 500;

    var number = 5;
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
        var shape = new createjs.Shape();
        var shapeWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var shapeHeight = 50;
        shape.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(0, 0, shapeWidth, shapeHeight);
        shape.x = i * 51;
        shape.y = canvas.height - 50;
        stage.addChild(shape);
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5kgbe3g/1/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get very complicated to divide a length randomly if you include constraints , such as min and max size of divisions, must maintain true randomness (can't cheat and just add last bit if the divisions don't fit perfectly).

So the easy way is to set a simple constraint. Divide length into n random lengths each length no shorter than x.

```
// length is the length to divide randomly
// count is the number of divisions
// min is the minimum division size
// array (optional) the array to add the data too. Will be created if not given
// returns array containing count items. Each item is a random value > min
// where the total sum of all the items is === length.
// If the array already has items then new items are added. Only the new 
// items will satisfy the length constraint.
// NOTE There is no vetting YOU MUST SUPPLY good arguments or the function
// will return nonsense.
function randomDiv(length,count,min,array = []){
    var rand, total = 0;  // total to normalise random values
    length -= count * min;  // get the remaining length after removing length
                            // used by min length
    var startAt = array.length; // If adding to array get the start index
    // get a set of random values and sum them 
    while(array.length - startAt < count){
         ran = Math.random();
         total += ran;
         array.push(ran);
     }
     // use the total sum of random values to
     // normalise the array items to be the correct length
     while(count --){
         array[startAt + count] = min + array[startAt + count] / total * length;
     }
     return array;
}
```

To use

```
// get 20 box widths to fit canvas width  no smaller than 10 pixels
var boxes = randomDiv(canvas.width, 20, 10);

// to reuse the array. Create a referance
var boxes = [];
// each time out call the function pass the referance and empty it or 
// result is added
boxes.length = 0;
boxes = randomDiv(canvas.width, 20, 10, boxes);
```

To create a set of boxes with differing qualities

```
// 100 small lengths  for half the canvas one or more pixels wide
var boxes = randomDiv(canvas.width / 2, 100, 1);
// get 10 more boxes for the remaining half larger than 30 pixels
boxes = randomDiv(canvas.width / 2, 10, 30, boxes);

// shuffle the array
var shuffled = [];
while(boxes.length > 0){
    shuffled.push(boxes.splice( Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length) , 1)[0]);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.